# How can a scraped HTML be different from the source code?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm scraping a list of restaurants from a website (with permission) and I have a problem. The html python scrapes from the website is different from the html in the source code. Less then half of the restaurants on their site are found in the html in python. This is what my code looks like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
import xlwt

url = 'https://www.example.com'

r = requests.get(url)
data = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
soup = data.find_all('span',{'class':'restaurant_name'})
print soup
```

Now I know it's incovenient, but I can't show the html since the company won't let me. I'm just wondering whether you guys in general know how the html downloaded by python can be different from the one in the source code and what I can do about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What other method are you comparing this to? Are you looking at the DOM inspector of your browser? That shows the *current state* of the site, not the initial source. If the site loads data via AJAX, those two things may differ considerably.

Comment: Have you considered Javascript may be employed to add restaurants dynamically?

Comment: Yes I'm looking at the inspector in my browser! I didn't know that makes a difference! What can I do to download the current state of the site?

Comment: I don't know how to use javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Selenium for this purpose. It will render your web page in run time just like your browser does. You can use Selenium with firefox, chrome or phantomjs.

**Selenium**

We use selenium basically to completely render our web page as most of the sites are made up of Modern JavaScript frameworks. Mostly it is used in developing Crawlers/Scrappers for gathering data from different pages of a website or Selenium is also used in web automation.

More on Selenium, read it here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
Also I have blog post on Slenium for the beginners. Check this one too http://blog.hassanmehmood.com/creating-your-first-crawler-in-python/

**Example**

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile_link = 'http://hassanmehmood.com'


class TitleScrapper(object):

    def __init__(self):

        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore") #Avoid startup screen
        fp.set_preference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional",  "about:blank")

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

    def scrape_profile(self):
        self.driver.get(profile_link)
        print self.driver.title
        self.driver.close()

    def scrape(self):
        self.scrape_profile()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = TitleScrapper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

Answer (score 5):

In a word, javascript. You're downloading the basic HTML page, but you're not a browser, and you're not downloading and running any of the javascript code that the browser would run. And many sites these days start with a very small HTML page, and use scripting to dynamically load and display additional data from the server.

Comment: How would I download the current state of the site?

Comment: @titusflex check above answer, you have to use selenium