# Scraping using Inspect element

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup, instagram, screen-scraping

I am trying to get some information from Instagram by scraping it. I have tried this code on twitter and it was working fine but it shows no result on Instagram both of the code are available here.

---

Twitter code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
theurl = "https://twitter.com/realmadrid"
thepage = urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
print(soup.find('div',{"class":"ProfileHeaderCard"}))
```

Result: Perfectly given.

---

Instagram Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
theurl = "https://www.instagram.com/barackobama/"
thepage = urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
print(soup.find('div',{"class":"_bugdy"}))
```

Result: None

Comment: If you look at the source, you will see the content is dynamically loaded so there is no `div._bugdy`

Comment: you need to use Selenium for this type of scrapping.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203059/how-can-a-scraped-html-be-different-from-the-source-code/37203351#37203351

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source, you will see the content is dynamically loaded so there is no `div._bugdy` in what is returned by your request, depending on what it is you want you may be able to pull it from the script json:

```
import requests
import re
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/barackobama/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
js = soup.find("script",text=re.compile("window._sharedData")).text
_json = json.loads((js[js.find("{"):js.rfind("}")+1]))
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(_json)
```

That gives you everything you see in the `<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = .....` in the source returned.

If you want to ge the followers then  you will need to use something like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), the site is pretty much all dynamically loaded content, to get the followers you need to click the link which is only visible if you are logged in, this will get you closer to what you  want:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
login = "https://www.instagram.com"
dr = webdriver.Chrome()

dr.get(login)

dr.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='_k6cv7']").click()
dr.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys(youruname")
dr.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("yourpass")
dr.find_element_by_css_selector("button._aj7mu._taytv._ki5uo._o0442").click()
time.sleep(5)
dr.get("https://www.instagram.com/barackobama")

dr.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href="/barackobama/followers/"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
for li in dr.find_element_by_css_selector("div._n3cp9._qjr85").find_elements_by_xpath("//ul/li"):
    print(li.text)
```

That pulls some text from the li tags that appear in the popup after you click the link, you can pull whatever you want from the unordered list:

[image]

Comment: But some of the things which can be seen from Inspect element is not available in the source such as user-ids of followers so how to get that.

Comment: @Ravi, have you looked at the json? The whole content is loaded by the script so you have nothing at all unless you use something like selenium of parse the json

Comment: Your code is working perfect but what I want to access is the user-ids of followers from https://www.instagram.com/barackobama/followers/ but for this source code do not give the results while the list is visible in inspect element.

Comment: @Ravi, that link does nothing even in the brower, you would need to simulate clicking the link with selenium, the site is completely dynamically created.

Comment: You also have to be logged in to get the link in the first place

Answer (score 0):

First of all there seems to be a typo in the address on line 3.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
theurl = "https://www.instagram.com/barackobama/"
thepage = urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
print(soup.find('div',{"class":"_bugdy"}))
```

Secondly, since you are working with dynamically loaded content, Python might not be able to see all the content you see when browsing the page in your browser.
In order to solve that there are different webdrivers, such as Selenium webdriver (http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) and PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) which emulate the browser and can wait for Javascript to generate/display data before looking it up.