# HTML request does not show everything as the html in browser

Tags: python, html, urllib

I am trying to obtain comments of a website using Python and urllib.
I am able to get the html, however, I noticed that the comment section of the html I got using python is missing.

Here's what I have using python:

```html
<div data-bv-product-id="6810124" data-bv-show="reviews" id="BVReviewsContainer">
</div>
```

(what's in between the div tags is empty)

Where as this is what it should look like(in the browser):

```
<div data-bv-product-id="6810124" data-bv-show="reviews" id="BVReviewsContainer">
    <div id="BVRRContainer">
        <div class="bv-cleanslate bv-cv2-cleanslate"> <div data-bv-v="contentList:1" class="bv-shared bv-core-container-437" data-product-id="6810124">
             .
             .
             .
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I am confounded as to why I am not getting the whole thing.

Comment: Where's your Python code? We can't really help you without it...

Comment: Or another theory I have is that you have some JS code insert that id="BVRRContainer" for you. Try to disable JS in your browser and inspect your HTML code, see if you still have those

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203059/how-can-a-scraped-html-be-different-from-the-source-code) post explains why scraped HTML isn't always the same; JavaScript can change the HTML of a website. One instance I've seen this happen is I believe on Archive of Our Own, where the actual body of a work was not available. According to that StackOverflow post, you should use Selenium to scrape it instead, as it essentially simulates the actual process that happens when a user accesses a page: the user opens a web browser (you can use your preferred web browser, like Chrome), then opens a page, and the page's JavaScript runs (through possible the `onload` event.