# Why is the source code of a website different from the code when inspected in browser? (For webscraping)

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on my first programming project so excuse any incorrect lingo.

My Goal: 
I am trying to web scrape from my local library's website. The end goal is to be able to automate renewing books on the website.

Progress: 
I have been successful at using Python, Selenium, and Webdriver to log into the library's website and go onto the 'Checkouts' page to view my loaned items. Then, I used Beautiful Soup to extract the HTML code of the website's 'Checkouts' page.

**Issue:** 
It looks like the HTML source code when I inspect the 'Checkouts' website (right-click and select 'Inspect' in Chrome browser) is different from the code when I look at the HTML source code (right-click and select 'View Source Code' in Chrome browser).

The HTML code when looking at source code aligns with what my Python code extracts, but is missing all the information I want to scrape.  However, the HTML code when inspecting the site does contain the information I want to scrape.

**Questions:**

1. Why is the HTML code different when I 'inspect' the site vs. 'View Source Code' from the Chrome browser? (Is this perhaps 'minification'?)
2. How can I extract the HTML code with the information I want to scrape?

I have included my code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/signin')

# Login details
username = 'abcdefghi'
password = 'abcd'

# Type Username
submitUsername = driver.find_element_by_id('userId')
submitUsername.send_keys(username)

# Type Password
submitPassword = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
submitPassword.send_keys(password)

# Press Enter
enter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_signin"]/div[2]/input[3]')
enter.click()

# Open Checkouts page
driver.get('https://account.torontopubliclibrary.ca/checkouts')

driver = requests.get('https://account.torontopubliclibrary.ca/checkouts').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a scraped HTML be different from the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203059/how-can-a-scraped-html-be-different-from-the-source-code)

Comment: 2 things that come to mind are 1) not waiting for everything to load, and 2) using a non-html5 parser

Answer (score 3):

On your first question: "Why is the HTML code different when I 'inspect' the site vs. 'View Source Code' from the Chrome browser? (Is this perhaps 'minification'?)"

"View Source Code" shows the HTML text response received from the server, when you request the page.

After this initial response is received, in the modern pages a lot of javascript is executed, which changes the initial html that is received from the server. 
When you "inspect" the page, all the changes made through javascript are reflected in what you see and are synced to what you see as a user in the browser, while the "View Source Code" always returns the initial response from the server, without any changes that happened after that.